# Windows form click event for panel does not work when another object is using it as a handle

Tags: image, winforms, c++-cli, controls, panel

I have an IC Image Control Grabber that is using a panel in a windows form as a handle (embedding the camera input in the form). I want to be able to click at some point on the panel and get the coordinates of the click in that panel. I have written that function and it works great before I embed the camera input. However, as soon as the camera is embedded the click event is not triggered when I click in the panel. Any ideas on what I can do to fix this problem?

Here is the documentation for the Grabber Object: (I call the setHWND() function)
http://www.imagingcontrol.com/en_US/support/documentation/class/Grabber.htm

Here is the relevant code I have written:

```
System::Void liveFeedPanel_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    System::Drawing::Point cursorPoint = liveFeedPanel->PointToClient(Cursor->Position);
    //do something with that point
}

System::Void MainForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    HWND hwnd = static_cast<HWND>(this->liveFeePanel->Handle.ToPointer());
    imageController->startCamera();
    imageController->startLive(hwnd);
}

void ImageController::startLive(HWND hwnd)
{
    if (grabber.isDevValid()) {
        grabber.setHWND(hwnd);
        grabber.setDefaultWindowPosition(false);
        grabber.setWindowSize(//the new size);
        grabber.startLive(true);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I hope the added code helps. I haven't been able to find any documentation of a similar problem.

Comment: Use Spy++ to have a look what it does with that panel.  With the expectation that it created its own child window inside the panel.  So mouse events go that window, not yours.  You'd have to intercept them before they are dispatched, IMessageFilter.  Could even be a window owned by another process, only a mouse hook could work then.  And of course, ask the vendor for support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to use the MouseDown event instead of the Click event. This ignored what was being clicked on in the panel and simply looked at wether the mouse was within the panel.